# Azure Table Store / Use Mongoose like Schema

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

I'm looking for a Mongoose like library to use Schemas on Azure Table Store (explicitly not Cosmos DB). For Google Cloud Store there is gstore (https://github.com/sebelga/gstore-node) is there something similar for ATS ?

Answer (score 0):

Peter, I'd recommend checking the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs)
It doesn't showcase Mongoose for ATS, but shows the use of NodeJs.

ATS is by default schemaless, as mentioned in the official documentation:

> Azure Table storage is a service that stores structured NoSQL data in the cloud, providing a key/attribute store with a schemaless design. Because Table storage is schemaless, it's easy to adapt your data as the needs of your application evolve.

There are also ways of using .Net here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet

Comment: I'm wondering if @peter-jaeger wasn't looking for a framework that would bring features like schema validation from Mongoose to ATS, like the mentioned `gstore-node` does.